# Log files for Solr on Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, solr, lucene, centos

I am using Tomcat6 to deploy Solr on CentOs. Where can I find the log files to figure out the error Solr is giving?

Comment: you can find it under the tomcat/logs/ or /var/logs/tomcat directory.

Comment: Under `tomcat/logs` I see many log files like `catalina.2012-08-16.log`, `host-manager.2012-08-16.log`, `manager.2012-08-16.log`, `catalina.out`, `localhost.2012-08-16.log`, `tomcat6-initd.log`... Which one is it, and where can I set the name of the log file?

Comment: catalina.out is the main file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the logging config from solr/ into a location on the classpath.

```
cp SOLR_HOME/example/resources/log4j.properties TOMCAT_HOME/conf/
```

Then restart your tomcat instance.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can find it in this directory apache-tomcat-x.x\logs
after that search for text file called "catalina" and the date of your search will be concatenated with a dot to the catalina file for example assume that we made a search at 2012-11-05 so the text file will lock like catalina.2012-11-05

Answer (score 0):

The error given by solr can be seen in catlina.out but if you want it in a separate file this is the way you can configure it.

Add the entried in **logging.proeperties** which is at the folder apache tomcat/conf.

```
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = solr.
```

Register the handler at the top in the file where all the other handlers are :

```
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

add the below entry at the last

```
org.apache.solr.level=INFO
org.apache.solr.handlers=6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

you will get a seperate solr.log file where in you will have all the solr logs.